# Rounding up an int divided by 10 to nearest int

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, int

I want to divide an int by 10 and get a whole number closest to rounded one, so
12 should give 1 and 17 should give 2

Heres my code:

```
int BonusValue;
int Str;

BonusValue = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Str) / 10));
```

Will this work?

Comment: Try it and see... Also, check out https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+math.round+options

Comment: Well, have you tried testing your code to see if it works? Have you identified a problem with your code?

Comment: Test it out yourself?

Comment: I'd test it out, have it not beign a part of quite complex code, which doesnt run just yet.

Comment: That will you surprising results because of midpoint rounding - inputs of `25` and `15` will both result in `2`.  Use Aganju's answer instead, which will give `3` and `2` respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that should work.

It is however much easier if you add half the rounding step, in your case 5, to the integer. Then you can do simple integer division:

`BonusValue = (Str+5) / 10`

Comment: Added bonus: This won't produce surprising results due to midpoint rounding to the nearest even number.

Comment: Thank you, I will be using this - it's suprisingly simple and effective.

Comment: It will however produce surprising results for negative inputs. If `Str` is `-14`, you'll get a result of `0`.

Comment: That's good, @MarkDickinson - who wants a negative bonus? ;-)

Comment: @Aganju: I think you have a different definition of "good" from me. :-) Do you really want a rounding method that rounds `-34` to `-2` (rather than `-3` or `-4`, both of which are closer to `-34/10`)? You should at least point out that your answer is only valid for nonnegative integers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Mathf.RoundToInt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html):

```
Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(17f/10f));
```

Answer (score 0):

That would work, but it is an inefficient way of doing it.

The best way in unity to do what you want is using the built in methods to do exactly that

```
BonusValue = Mathf.RountToInt(Str/10f);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work but what round type do you need? Check this:[MidpointRounding Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx)